# Dictionary order relation on the plane $\mathbb{R} ×\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, relations

I am self studing munkres topology  book.
I don't understand the example.

Definition: Suppose that A abd B are two sets with order $<_{A}$ and $<_{B}$ respectively. Define an order relation $<$ on $A×B$ by defining $a_1 ×b_1 < a_2 × b_2$ if $a_1 <_A a_2$ or  if $a_1 = a_2
$ and $b_1 <_B b_2 $. It is called the dictionary order relation on $A×B$

Example 11:Consider the dictionary order on the plane $\mathbb{R} ×\mathbb{R}$. In this order the point p is less than every point lying above it on the vertical line through p, and p is less than every point to the right of this vertical line.

In $\mathbb{R} ×\mathbb{R}$ how the dictionary order relation $p<q$ imply $q$ is to the right of vertical line $p$ is on ,or above it on the same vertical line?

Comment: Write from definition what it means for $p < q$. This is just restating the definition using words

Comment: @Jakobian if $p=(p_1 , p_2)$ and $q=(q_1 , q_2) $ then $p<q$ implies $ p_1 × p_2 < q_1 × q_2 $ if $p_1< q_1$ or if$ p_1 =q_1 $and $p_2< q_2$. How to proceed now?

Comment: @Alexander Think about what "$p_1<q_1$
 or $(p_1=q_1$ and $p_2<q_2)$" means geometrically.

Comment: @Arthur If $p_1 = q_1$ and $p_2 < q_2 $ then q is above p on the vertical line through p . And if $p_1<q_1$ then q is on the right side of vertical line through p

Comment: Exactly! And that's precisely what Munkres is saying.